# Как достать элемент таблицы, который является членом колекции другой таблицы?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Здравствуйте,  я недавно начал изучать asp.net mvc и решил сделать не большой проект, но столкнулся с проблемой. Мне нужно достать массив байтов с таблицы Picture, которая являеться элементо коллекциия таблицы Users.

```
@model IEnumerable<Aut.Models.ApplicationUser>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.Raw("<img style='width:80px; height:60px;' src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,"
                                + Convert.ToBase64String(item.Pictures) + "\" />")
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

но максимум, что я могу, это обратиться к пикчрс как к элементу бд. Я использовал asp.net identity для авторизации и привязал по usersid таблицу Pictures.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ICollection<Picture> Pictures { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        Pictures = new List<Picture>();
    }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class Picture
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; } // размер картинки
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }

    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

ну и под конец мой контролер, который должен принимать айди юзера и масив байтов изображения

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ApplicationUser au ,Picture pic, HttpPostedFileBase uploadImage)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && uploadImage!=null)
        {
            byte[] imageData = null;

            using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(uploadImage.InputStream))
            {
                imageData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(uploadImage.ContentLength);
            }

            pic.Image = imageData;
            au.Pictures.Add(pic);

            db.Users.Add(au);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("UserDetails");
        }
        return View(pic);
    }
```

Спасибо заранее за помощь, буду очень благодарен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно передать в `src` свойство `Picture.Image`
Попробуйте так:

```
@model IEnumerable<Aut.Models.ApplicationUser>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    foreach (var picture in item.Pictures)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.Raw("<img style='width:80px; height:60px;' src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,"
                                + Convert.ToBase64String(picture.Image) + "\" />")
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

Comment: ,спасибо большое, первый раз обратился на стэковерфлоу и такая удача